# The circle is not going ontop of the image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, python-3.9

This is the code that draws a circle ontop of a board.
The problem is that the second frame is going ontop of the other.
How do I fix this?

The cide is:

- Making a Frame called frame.
- Packing it
- Making anither frame called iframe5
- packing that
- Creating a cavas in iframe5 called c
- Packing that
- creates an oval in the cavas
- Puts an image in the first fram
- Main Loop

## Import required libraries

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# Create an instance of tkinter window
win = Tk()

# Define the geometry of the window
win.geometry("480x480")

frame = Frame(win, width=480, height=480,bd = 1)
frame.pack()
#frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.5)


iframe5 = Frame(frame, bd=2, relief=RAISED)
iframe5.pack(expand=1, fill=X, pady=10, padx=5)


c = Canvas(iframe5, bg='white', width=340, height=100)
c.pack()
c.create_oval(30,30,60,60)


# Create an object of tkinter ImageTk
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Board.png"))
# Create a Label Widget to display the text or Image
#c.pack()
label = Label(frame, image = img)
label.pack()



#c.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add the required image so that we can [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) your problem. Also, to make the question clearer, you could add an image of the current output.

Comment: I have almost solved my problem

Comment: I will update when solved

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to first `pack` the widget which you want to appear at top. `pack` method or any other geometry manager method is used to fix the position inside the GUI, so

```
label=Label(text='hello')
label2=Label(text'hello2')
label2.pack()
label.pack()
```

from the above example, the widget you have packed first would appear to be at top.

if you write a widget and don't use any geometry manager, tkinter would only save the reference to that widget.

Comment: I have already solved it myself by putting the image on the canvas and making the circle another image and having transparency

Comment: @charsarg , good that you have solved, you can add that as an asnwer on this question, that would be helpfull for others someday.